# Is there a syntax or command to take user input to a variable in mongo script?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am working with a mongoDB script where in I want to take an input and I'll place it to a variable which i can play with.

i have tried

```
var ABcD = prompt('type a word: ');
print(ABcD);
```

but I think this only works on other javascript, not in mongoDB.
Any help?

Comment: You're trying to give direct access of database to the end user, which is not a good thing

Comment: i work this on the back end, and just exploring, so that not every time ill edit the script i made instead

Comment: The `mongo` shell currently has very limited I/O support. If you want to prompt for user input you'll have to do so using a programming language driver or shell script.

Comment: Ok I'll try modifiying my file.js via bash script . hohoho thanks @Stennie

Comment: @Stennie: Did you achieve this?